# how to write code in xcode that will be supported for all the sizes of iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4

The Problem is, kept size none in the viewcontroller.xib, and wrote code its running in iphone4 ,and normal iphone but the view is not supporting for iphone5 please tell me how to design for all iphone sizes

Comment: [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275144/how-to-make-xib-compatible-with-both-iphone-5-and-iphone-4-devices)

Comment: Check out this similar problem:
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576356/how-does-one-get-ui-user-interface-idiom-to-work-with-iphone-os-sdk-3-2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important thing we need to keep in mind is you have to place **Default-568h@2x.png** . Then only it starts supporting for iPhone 5 . You have to write this line for handling the iPhone 5 . iPhone5 screen size is 640x1136 . So the images which you are using for iPhone 4/4s are also suits for iPhone 5 except background images because view height is 176 pixels more in iPhone 5 .

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height>=1136)
    {
    // write some code here for positioning the element 

    }
```

Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: let u know as soon as possible

Comment: check out my updated answer . Don't forget to place Default-568h@2x.png in the Project

Comment: its working but in the view the label positions are not changing

Comment: The problem is alignment of texts in viewcontroller.xib files

Comment: how to align the viewcontroller texts

Comment: If you want to make your own frame then you have to write the code like this in viewDIdload if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height>=1136)
    {
    // write some code here for positioning the element 
textfield.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
    }

Comment: you can also use the Autoresize Mask

Comment: if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height>=1136) {
        // write some code here for positioning the element textfield.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
        NSLog(@"retina");
    }

Comment: my view size changed how to solve this problem

Comment: in which device iPhone 4 or 5?

Comment: in iphone 5 at the bottom of the screen label texts is not fixing

Comment: in the if(UI_USERINTERFACE_IDIOM  ).... condition fix the frame manually

Comment: how to fix the frame manually plz give me any idea

Comment: in the if(UI_USERINTERFACE_IDIOM ).... conditon write textview.frame =  CGRectMake(10,2,100,100);