# White bar for iPhone 5 in simulator

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, ios-simulator, uinavigationbar

my app shows a white bar on the top for the 4 inch screen (= iPhone 5). For iPhone 4, it works nicely (no white bar is shown). What is the problem (iOS SDK 6.1)?

This is, how I add the UINavigationController:

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:exploreViewController];

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Best,
Stefan[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using a nib or a storyboard?

Comment: I am using a nib and add an UINavigationController programatically. I use the UINavigationController to display different center views (pink colored) and a UINavigationBar (green colored).

Comment: make sure that you're setting up the nib to be friendly to both sizes of devices. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275144/how-to-make-xib-compatible-with-both-iphone-5-and-iphone-4-devices

Comment: Thanks, but it is already set for the 4 inch screen ;-) I've attached a screenshot of the Interface Builder settings.

Comment: can you post how you are adding the navigation controller? also when using the Interface Builder and adding nav controllers programmatically it's a good idea to set the Top Bar to "Navigation Bar", so whatever you add in IB won't be covered by the nav bar.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];`

to

`[self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];`

You should be adding the Navigation Controller in your `AppDelegate`. [Here's a good tutorial](http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/).