# Use two different nib files for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, xib, nib

Is there any way to detect what device the user is using, then using that information, make the application use a specific `nib` file?

Right now, the code that I have is

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
  if(isiPhone5){
    self.RootViewController = @"RootViewController_iPhone5";
  }
  else{
    self.RootViewController = @"RootViewController_iPhone4";
  }
}
```

My other code for finding the device works and tells me what device the user is using, yet doesn't actually change the .xib file from `RootViewController_iPhone4.xib` to `RootViewController_iPhone5.xib`. Is there any way to do this?

I don't want to use auto layout, because I would like to have other custom things happen depending upon the device, such as different button names in the view controller if the device being used is an iPhone 4 verses an iPhone 5

Comment: Go for AutoSizing instead of creating two diff XIBs.

Comment: Here is the simple example for that. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275144/how-to-make-xib-compatible-with-both-iphone-5-and-iphone-4-devices

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] will get you the iphone device version name...

Comment: @PuneethKamath Great! Now what would it return if the iphone was iphone 4/5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275144/how-to-make-xib-compatible-with-both-iphone-5-and-iphone-4-devices/13283851#comment34745300_13283851

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way..

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height ==568)
    {
          self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
          self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone4" bundle:nil];
    }
```

**Updated Answer**

check this...
[Black Screen for screen detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12396752/1673099)

Comment: See my updated answer & must make sure that you put the splash screen for screen detection.

Comment: I'm using the newest version. Also, It can detect what device the user is using, just it won't change the .xib file from RootViewController to RootViewController_iPhone5 when I try that code. Do you have any other ideas, or other things I have to do like make new class files for RootViewController_iPhone5?

Comment: Stupid question - where would this code go (which file)?

Answer (score 1):

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
     if (IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"YourViewController~iphone5" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"YourViewController~iphone" bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Try something like this

Comment: I get _No visible @interface for 'UIResponder' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'_

Comment: are you creating view controller? or a view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the following way

create a macro in App delegate so that it will be used through out the Project. It will be based on the screen height for the device.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Now you can test the condition for iphone 4 and iphone 5

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){


    if(IS_IPHONE_5){


        self.window.RootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController_iPhone5" bundle:nil];

    }
    else
    {
        self.window.RootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone 4 Classic

        //first always target 4 for better performance & practice.
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
    }
}else {
//it's ipad
}
```